# When trying to build the OONF package for DLEP implementation there occurs a error with tomcrypt.sh not being found, how do I install tomcrypt?

Tags: apt, compiling

When trying to build the OONF package onto my ubuntu for the latest dlep implementation it give me this error:

#include polarssl/sha1.h

it reffers to the tomcrypt.h who isn't there, I can't seem to find a apt-get install tomcrypt or anything that comes close to this.

Can Anyone help me?

Much regards

EDIT: have installed all libtomcrypt packages, have updates on and still the same error!
EDIT 2: PolarSSL not found (before building the git)

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in this:

https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/utopic/universe/libtomcrypt-dev/

Basically, run this in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libtomcrypt-dev
```

Comment: I tried that already and I got 'unable to locate package libtomcrypt-dev'

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: Newest one 14.04.2LTS

Comment: odd.  are you up to date on updates?

Comment: Yes I'm, been stuck for days now, not sure what to do right now.